# Exception in native call from JS: Unexpected token '<'

Tags: react-native

Installing an existing React-native application is throwing error.

Logcat error:

```
E/unknown:ReactNative: Exception in native call from JS
  com.facebook.react.devsupport.JSException: Unexpected token '<'
      at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.NativeRunnable.run(Native Method)
      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
      at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage(Unknown Source:0)
      at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
      at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$4.run(Unknown Source:37)
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:920)
   Caused by: com.facebook.jni.CppException: Unexpected token '<'`

    no stack
      ... 8 more
  D/SoLoader: Loaded: libyoga.so
  E/ReactNativeJNI: Attempting to call JS function on a bad application bundle: HMRClient.setup()
  E/unknown:ReactNative: Exception in native call
      java.lang.RuntimeException: Attempting to call JS function on a bad application bundle: HMRClient.setup()
          at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.NativeRunnable.run(Native Method)
          at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
          at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage(Unknown Source:0)
          at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
          at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$4.run(Unknown Source:37)
          at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:920)
  E/ReactNativeJNI: Attempting to call JS function on a bad application bundle: AppRegistry.runApplication()
  E/unknown:ReactNative: Exception in native call
      java.lang.RuntimeException: Attempting to call JS function on a bad application bundle: AppRegistry.runApplication()
          at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.NativeRunnable.run(Native Method)
          at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
          at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage(Unknown Source:0)
          at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
          at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$4.run(Unknown Source:37)
          at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:920)
  D/SoLoader: init exiting
```

Output of `npx react-native info`

```
info Fetching system and libraries information...

System:
    OS: macOS 12.4
    CPU: (8) x64 Apple M1
    Memory: 40.87 MB / 8.00 GB
    Shell: 5.8.1 - /bin/zsh
  Binaries:
    Node: 14.19.0 - /usr/local/bin/node
    npm: 6.14.16 - /usr/local/bin/npm
    Watchman: 2022.06.13.00 - /opt/homebrew/bin/watchman
  SDKs:
    iOS SDK:
      Platforms: iOS 15.0, DriverKit 20.4, macOS 11.3, tvOS 15.0, watchOS 8.0
    Android SDK:
      API Levels: 29, 30, 31, 32
      Build Tools: 29.0.2, 30.0.2, 30.0.3, 32.0.0, 32.1.0
      System Images: android-30 | Intel x86 Atom_64, android-32 | Google APIs ARM 64 v8a
  IDEs:
    Android Studio: 2021.1 AI-211.7628.21.2111.8193401
    Xcode: 13.0/13A233 - /usr/bin/xcodebuild
  npmPackages:
    react: 16.9.0 => 16.9.0
    react-native: 0.61.1 => 0.61.1
```

**Steps to reproduce**

Create a React native app with version 0.61.1,

- Install npm dependencies: `npm i` (tried `npm i --legacy-peer-deps`)
- Run metro server: `npx react-native start --reset-cache`
- Run android build: `npx react-native run-android` (I am using Android studio to run the app)

I have already been through following issue resolutions but nothing worked for me:

- https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/21074
- https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/32875
- https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/14139

[image]

Comment: wait can you share your code where its crashing?

Comment: It is crashing when I am running `npx react-native run-android` command

Answer (score 1):

```
First clear your cache and node_module using the below command 

cd android && ./gradlew cleanBuildCache && cd .. &&
watchman watch-del-all && rm -rf node_modules/ &&
rm -rf $TMPDIR/react-native-packager-cache-* && rm -rf 
$TMPDIR/metro-bundler-cache-* &&  
yarn cache clean && yarn install && 
yarn start --reset-cache

After done this change you babel.config.js

module.exports = {
presets: [['module:metro-react-native-babel-preset', {
   unstable_disableES6Transforms: true
}]],
};
```

Comment: I tried your solution but still facing the same issue.